# How to plot a 2D-contour by using data from 3X3 matrix?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to plot reciprocal space maps using my x, y and z data that is present in a matrix. My X and Y is a mesh grid and Z value is independent of X and Y values (Or also coordinates).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data= np.loadtxt('s1_101.txt', unpack=True)

x = data[0,:]
y = data[1,:]
z = data[2,:]
L = 1.54060

y = np.array(y) + 0.
z = np.array(z) + 0.

X = [ np.cos(y) - np.cos(x) ]
X = np.array(X) + 0.
X = X/L
Y = [ np.sin(y) + np.sin(y) ]
Y = np.array(Y) + 0.
Y = Y/L
main = [X,Y,z]
amen = np.transpose(main)
```